# && won't work in a boolean method

Tags: java, boolean

When I try to make a public Boolean, it gives me the error

> The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) Boolean, Float

the code is:

```
 public boolean mouseHover(int mouseX, int mouseY, float x, float y, float height, float width){
        if(((mouseX >= x) && (x + width) && (mouseY >= y) && (mouseY <= y + height))){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: *pleas answer soon* this is a free service, you can't ask for us trying to solve your problems like they have higher preference than other questions in the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(x + width)
```

is not a boolean expression. Did you mean to check

```
mouseX <= (x + width)
```

perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

`(mouseX >= x) && (x + width)` makes no sense. There is no condition in the right parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

`x + width` does not yield to Boolean comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Each individual term being joined by the && must be capable of being evaluated as a bool

```
x + width
```

Does not satisfy that condition.

In general, it is not allowed to write if x is less than y and z like this

```
if( x < y && z)
```

instead write

```
if(x < y && x < z)
```